# Comments in Google Place

Tags: android, json, search, google-places-api

I saw in the official documentation of google places : https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search

that the response gave from the server to search is :

```
"results" : [
   {
      "formatted_address" : "529 Kent Street, Sydney NSW, Australia",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : -33.8750460,
            "lng" : 151.2052720
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
      "id" : "827f1ac561d72ec25897df088199315f7cbbc8ed",
      "name" : "Tetsuya's",
      "rating" : 4.30,
      "reference" : "CnRmAAAAmmm3dlSVT3E7rIvwQ0lHBA4sayvxWEc4nZaXSSjRtfKRGoYnfr3d5AvQGk4e0u3oOErXsIJwtd3Wck1Onyw6pCzr8swW4E7dZ6wP4dV6AsXPvodwdVyqHgyGE_K8DqSp5McW_nFcci_-1jXb5Phv-RIQTzv5BjIGS0ufgTslfC6dqBoU7tw8NKUDHg28bPJlL0vGVWVgbTg",
      "types" : [ "restaurant", "food", "establishment" ]
   }...
```

I would like to know if it is posible to reach info like comments, 
basically to reach more info that those 8 variables.

Tx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is disponible en :

```
    "results" : [
"reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "quality"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Simon Bengtsson",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/104675092887960962573",
            "text" : "Just went inside to have a look at Google. Amazing.",
            "time" : 1338440552869
         },
         {
           "aspects" : [
              {
                 "rating" : 3,
                 "type" : "quality"
              }
             ],
            "author_name" : "Felix Rauch Valenti",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/103291556674373289857",
            "text" : "Best place to work :-)",
            "time" : 1338411244325
         },
         {
           "aspects" : [
              {
                 "rating" : 3,
                 "type" : "quality"
              }
             ],
            "author_name" : "Chris",
            "text" : "Great place to work, always lots of free food!",
            "time" : 1330467089039
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "establishment" ],
      "url" : "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=10281119596374313554",
      "vicinity" : "48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont",
      "website" : "http://www.google.com.au/"
   },
```

Official page: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details